# Creating unequal age bands in C# Metadata

Tags: c#, function, date, math, metadata

I need to create a set of unequal age groupings from a patient dataset in C# using Visual Studio 2010 using a Metada method

The age groups are <= 40, 41-50, 51-60, 61-70, 70+

Currently we have some code to do 5 year age groups:

```
public string AgeGroup5Yrs
    {
        get
        {
            int range = Math.Abs(Age / 5) * 5;
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", range, range + 5);
        }
    }
```

And some 10 year(equal agegroups)

```
public string AgeGroup
    {
        get
        {
            int range = Math.Abs(Age / 10) * 10;
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", range, range + 10);
        }
    }
```

However I need some unequal groups! Any ideas? I am new to C# so any help is useful

Comment: UPDATE:Had a quick attempt using if then else: - didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `Array.BinarySearch` so should be pretty performant. `indexOf` ends up containing the index of the next-larger boundary.

```
static int[] boundaries = new[] { 40, 50, 60, 70 };
static string AgeGroupFor
{
    get
    {
        int indexOf = Array.BinarySearch(boundaries, Age);
        if (indexOf < 0)
            indexOf = ~indexOf;
        if (indexOf == 0)
            return "<= " + boundaries[0];
        if (indexOf == boundaries.Length)
            return (boundaries[boundaries.Length - 1]) + "+";
        return (boundaries[indexOf - 1]+1) + "-" + boundaries[indexOf];
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could pre-calculate the strings:

```
static int[] boundaries = new[] { 40, 50, 60, 70 };
static string[] groups = new[] { "<= 40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70", "70+" };
static string AgeGroupFor
{
    get
    {
        int indexOf = Array.BinarySearch(boundaries, Age);
        if (indexOf < 0)
            indexOf = ~indexOf;
        return groups[indexOf];
    }
}
```